# Do four natural numbers exist which satisfy these constraints?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, diophantine-equations

Do four natural numbers $a,b,c$ and $d$ exist such that the following three conditions are true?

$$a^2+b^2+2d^2=c^2$$
$$\sqrt{a^2+d^2}\in\mathbb{N}$$
$$\sqrt{b^2+d^2}\in \mathbb{N}$$

Comment: why do you want to know???

Comment: As $a = 0,   b = 0,   d = \pm\frac{\sqrt{c^2}}{\sqrt{2}}$ are the only solutions; I'd guess no...

Comment: ? What? @JohnWO

Comment: It's just my severely uneducated guess. Please, prove it my assumption wrong...

Comment: @JohnWO I don't understand what you're saying

Comment: This is equivalent to $A^4+B^4=c^2$  with $A^2=a^2+d^2, B^2=b^2+d^2$. This has no solutions. See http://2000clicks.com/mathhelp/PythagNoSolutionToA4PlusB4EqualsC2.aspx

Comment: Does $0 \in \Bbb N$ according to your definition of the set of natural numbers?

Comment: @DavidP No, it has $A^2 + B^2 = c^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The smallest example is $a=9, b=16, c = 25, d = 12$.  Of course, any integer multiple of this will do.  There are other solutions as well.

Comment: Now I can draw it [link](http://www.arturwrobel.com/Zadania/wzory/trojkat_prostokatny.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You want $(a^2+d^2)+(b^2+d^2)=c^2$ and also $a^2+d^2=x^2$ and $b^2+d^2=y^2$.

The solutions of $x^2+y^2=c^2$ are $x=2mnk,y=(m^2-n^2)k,c=(m^2+n^2)k$ where $(m,n)=1$ and $m>n$.

Now we have the equations $a^2+d^2=(2mnk)^2$ and $b^2+d^2=((m^2-n^2)k)^2$.

Do the same and see what happens:)

Comment: What I have to know about k?

Comment: @marth k is any integer,say that it gives you multiples. This algorithm will you give you all the solutions.

Comment: But triangle [link](http://www.arturwrobel.com/Zadania/wzory/trojkat_prostokatny.jpg) can't be generated by the algorytm. Am I right?

Comment: k=5 (only 5 divide 15 and 20 and 25) then $m=3/\sqrt2$ and $n=1/\sqrt2 $ and something going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For any [Pythagorean triple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) $(x,y,z)$ (such  that $x^2+y^2=z^2$)
denote
$$
a=x^2,\\
b=y^2,\\
c=z^2,\\
d=xy.
$$

Then
$$
a^2+b^2+2d^2 = a^2+b^2+2ab = (a+b)^2=z^4=c^2,
$$
$$
a^2+d^2=x^4+x^2y^2=x^2(x^2+y^2)=(xz)^2,
$$
$$
b^2+d^2=y^4+x^2y^2=y^2(y^2+x^2)=(yz)^2.
$$

Answer (score 0):

It can be shown $a^2+b^2=q^2$ has solutions $b=2mn, a=m^2-n^2, q=m^2+n^2$.

If we let  $c'^2-2d'^2=1$ where $c'$ and $d'$ are solutions to [Pell's Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation) and let $c=qc'$ and $d=qd'$ then we have solutions to the above equation.

So there are infinitely many solutions.